# Excel VBA copy Cell contents to a InkEdit text box and keep for formatting including colour/bold etc

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet where some cells have multicolored text and is in bold/underline/italic.

I need to be able to pull the cell contents and display the information on a form keeping the same formatting.

I have come across InkEdit control which supports RichText but I am unable to copy from cell to this box.

Help please

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a standard Active-X control. Why not give a link to it, and its documentation.

Comment: Its the InkEdit Control don't why I said InkPad

This is one of the standard libraries that you can find in Tools->References

Comment: I see. There is a commercial product called InkPad, and it seemed possible that this was some sort of third-party control related to that. Perhaps you should edit the question.

Comment: @user3447974 My First Bounty!!! Yeah Baby!! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The problem seems to be that the Excel Object Model deeply buries the RTF formatting of the contents of a cell and provides no easy method to extract it.

Here is a kludge which seems to sort of work:

```
Sub CopyRichText(source As Range, target As InkEdit)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    target.Text = source.Text
    n = Len(target.Text)
    For i = 1 To n
        target.SelStart = i - 1
        target.SelLength = 1
        target.SelBold = source.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
        target.SelColor = source.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color
        target.SelFontName = source.Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle
        target.SelFontSize = source.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
        target.SelItalic = source.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic
        'target.SelUnderline = source.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline '-- doesn't work as expected!
    Next i
    target.SelStart = n
    target.SelLength = 0
End Sub
```

Used like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    CopyRichText Range("A1"), Me.InkEdit1
End Sub
```

For example, in A1 I have:

[image]

Then when I show the userform it looks like:

[image]

There seems to be an outright bug in the inkedit's `SelUnderline` method. Uncomment that line to see what I mean. Perhaps there is some workaround.

I suspect that the above is somewhat fragile. I haven't tested it all that much. If it works for you (perhaps suitably tweaked) -- good. If not, I suspect that there is a deep-magic approach using the clipboard. InkEdit controls don't have paste methods -- but it does have an `Hwnd` method which sounds like it could provide a target for a Window's paste.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the resolution you found and it does work but its very slow to update the control probably the control itself, tried with just 1, my project would require 20, need to find another way round this.

Comment: If you want to *display* the formatted contents of a cell (but not edit the contents in the userform) you could look into copying the cell as a picture, loading into a temp file, and then putting it into an image control. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to (at runtime) load images directly from the clipboard.

Comment: I hardly ever use the With statement but I think you might use it here to squeeze some extra speed.   `With source.Characters(i, 1).Font`

Comment: @SMeaden That is a good recommendation. Perhaps it could address some of OP's speed concerns, although with better answers now available it is probably moot.

Answer (score 7):

The InkEdit control supports pasting of rich text, so all you really need to do is copy the `Range`, then paste it into the control.  Since the control exposes it's `.hWnd`, all you need to do is use the SendMessage API function to send a WM_PASTE message:

```
'UserForm1
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias _
            "SendMessageW" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
            ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const WM_PASTE = &H302

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    RangeToInkEdit ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), InkEdit1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Sub RangeToInkEdit(source As Range, target As InkEdit)
    source.Copy
    SendMessage InkEdit1.hwnd, WM_PASTE, 0&, 0&
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Note that this *also* has a slight issue similar to @JohnColeman's method - it doesn't do that great of a job at picking up the colors.  This appears to be a problem that Excel has in the encoding of RTF that it sends to the clipboard rather than an issue with the InkEdit control itself (you can confirm that by copying and pasting into WordPad, which is basically an RTF editor). Some colors work, others don't - all of them will be reduced in color depth to basically the closest color that RTF supports.

[image: End result]

Comment: I can't believe that you posted a similar answer to mine less than a hour before me...lol. I do a couple of different things with it; or I wouldn't have posted it.  Nice answer.Great minds think a like!!!

Comment: This is quite nice. I wish that I could have split the bounty between you and @ThomasInzina since you have similar answers that were almost simultaneous. You both confirmed my hunch that some sort of deep magic involving `hWnd` is possible.

Comment: @JohnColeman - Only shallow magic - if I could figure out how Word keeps the color formatting and a rich text box doesn't, *that* would be the deep magic...

Comment: @Comintern My knowledge of windows messaging is pretty shallow. I've always been impressed by people who are able to augment VBA with Windows API calls.

Answer (score 4):

I provide two functions to work with an InkEdit Control.

- PasteToControl: Uses an API call to paste data from the ClipBoard into the InkEdit Control
- PutInClipBoard:  This copies text into the ClipBoard.  This function is needed because if you set the InkEdit text property (e.g. InkEdit.Text = InkEdit.Text & " Hello!") you'll lose all your formatting.  InkEdit.TextRTF won't work either.

[image]

### [image]

```
Private Declare Function PasteToControl Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, Optional ByVal wMsg As Long = &H302, Optional ByVal wParam As Long = 0, Optional lParam As Any = 0&) As Long

'http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18632

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
    InkEdit1.Text = vbCrLf

    Range("A6").Copy
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd

    PutInClipBoard vbCrLf & "How about Range?" & vbCrLf
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd
    Range("A2:G4").Copy
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd

    PutInClipBoard vbCrLf & "Can we do Tables?" & vbCrLf
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd
    Sheet4.ListObjects("Orders").Range.Copy
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd

    PutInClipBoard vbCrLf & "Pictures?"
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd
    Sheet4.Shapes("Picture 1").Copy
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd

    PutInClipBoard vbCrLf & "Charts?"
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd
    Sheet4.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Copy
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd

    PutInClipBoard vbCrLf & "Can we take a snapshot of a Range?" & vbCrLf
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd
    Range("A6:I12").CopyPicture
    PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd

End Sub

Sub PutInClipBoard(Text As String)
    Dim clip As DataObject
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText Text
    clip.PutInClipBoard

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. I rarely think to alias my API calls like that (too used to using them exactly as documented I suppose).  Like you said, "great minds think alike".

Comment: I originally wanted the user to only need the one line of code.  I had added the PutInClipBoard function because I couldn't figure out another way to add text to the InkEdit control without losing the formatting.

Comment: You can always wrap it something like this (apologies for the 1 liner):  `Sub PutInInkBox(Target As Object): Target.Copy: PasteToControl InkEdit1.hWnd: End Sub`.  Then you can call it like `PutInInkBox Range("A6")` or `PutInInkBox Sheet4.Shapes("Picture 1")`.  It would need error trapping of course.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I actually considered it but I wanted to include taking a snapshot of the range using `Range.CopyPicture`.  That would mean I would have to add another parameter to `PutInInkBox`.    So I opted to keep it simple.

Comment: If we set the `SelStart` the data will be inserted at that point.  Maybe I should wrap it into a `Sub InsertIntoInk(ink As InkEdit, InsertionPoint As Long, Data As Variant)`.   This way Data could be a string or an Object.

Comment: This is very nice. I like the architecture of this solution

Comment: @JohnColeman Those are strong words coming from a Computer Science teacher.  I appreciate it more than you know. Thanks

Comment: This is great thanks, 1 more question is there anyway to change size of font so when paste it can be larger or smaller or keep to font size of the inkedit box.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be able to edit the text?  If not, then I would try copying the range and pasting it as a picture in the UserForm.  Check Stephen Bullen's [PastePicture](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Excel/Default.htm) example for code.

Comment: The OP wasn't specific on that point. Bullen's PastePicture looks promising (if combined with code to copy a cell as a picture). It is possible that it would need tweaking since a lot has changed since Excel 97 (which Bullen's code seems to target).

Answer (score 0):

So... awhile ago, I wanted to use markdown in Excel's UserForms. I created a simple parser and lexer that I called SimpleDown. It works fantastically for it's obvious limitations. It currently uses a MSForms.Frame as the base container and then uses MSForms.Label(s) as each element of SimpleDown.

Below is an example of it:

```
# Header Test|| 
---||
* Unordered List 1||
* Unordered List 2||
TESTING of stuff....
```

Above will produce something like the following:

## HEADER

---

- Unordered List 1
- Unordered List 2

TESTING of stuff.....

---

After looking at Mr. Coleman's code, I realized that one wouldn't actually need to use Range, Cell, or anything like that. Instead, we could do the following:

## Process:

- Create subroutines for each specific style of markdown/rich text/etc... that you want to use.
- Create a parser that could identify which subroutine to call when it gets to a section/portion of the supplied text/string.
- As you add text to **inkbox**, have a lexer determine what subroutine to call for a each subsection of the text. Pass it the **inkbox** obj, start_pos, section_length.

yeah... this should work.

Edit... here's the code

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "cls_SimpleMarkdown"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Option Explicit
' ==========================================================================
' Class Name        : clsSimpleMarkdown
' Module Type       : Class
' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Description       :
'  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
' EXAMPLE
'   # Header Test||
'   ---||
'   * Unordered List 1||
'   * Unordered List 2||
'   TESTING of stuff I don't how this works. Spelling is diffuclt but something something something.
' ==========================================================================

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Consumed Events
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Defined Events
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Enumerations & Types
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Class Variables
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private ufBaseForm As MSForms.Frame
Private ufMarkDown As MSForms.Frame

Private Const ELM_LEFT As Double = 16
Private Const ELM_OL_LEFT As Double = 30
Private Const ELM_GAP As Double = 10
Private Const ELM_HR_GAP As Double = 5

'Private cComponents As Collection
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Class: Initialization & Termination
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
End Sub
' ------------------
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
End Sub

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Class Properties
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Using Events
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Public Subroutines
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Public Sub Clear()
    

End Sub
Public Sub Build(parentObj As Object, compName As String, dleft As Double, dTop As Double, dHeight As Double, dWidth As Double)
    Call Create_ufBaseForm(parentObj, compName, dleft, dTop, dHeight, dWidth)
    Call BuildAboveBan(ufBaseForm)
End Sub
' ------------------
Public Sub AddMarkdown(ByVal sContents As String)
    ' // Remove inner-frame, which clears all data
    If Not ufMarkDown Is Nothing Then
        UserForm1.Controls.Remove ufMarkDown.name
        Set ufMarkDown = Nothing
    End If
    ' // Reset collections to empty it
    'Set cComponents = New Collection
    Call Build_Markdown(sContents)
    
End Sub
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Private Subroutines
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Sub Build_Markdown(ByVal sContents As String)
    Dim dataArr As Variant: dataArr = Split(sContents, "||")
    Dim current_top As Double: current_top = 0
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' // Build container for parsed text
    Call Create_ufMarkDown(ufBaseForm)
    
    For i = LBound(dataArr) To UBound(dataArr)
        ' // Creates random number to ensure no elements are named the same
        Dim sClean_Data As String: sClean_Data = Clean_N_Trim(dataArr(i))
        Dim randomNum As Integer:  randomNum = Int((300 - 200 + 1) * Rnd + 200)
        Dim sLeft_Two As String:   sLeft_Two = Left(sClean_Data, 2)
        
        
        If sLeft_Two = "# " Then
            sClean_Data = Right(sClean_Data, Len(sClean_Data) - 2)
            current_top = Create_Header(ufMarkDown, oConcat("_", sClean_Data, randomNum), current_top, sClean_Data)
        ElseIf sLeft_Two = "* " Then
            sClean_Data = Right(sClean_Data, Len(sClean_Data) - 2)
            current_top = Create_OL(ufMarkDown, oConcat("_", sClean_Data, randomNum), current_top, sClean_Data)
        ElseIf sLeft_Two = "--" Then
            sClean_Data = Right(sClean_Data, Len(sClean_Data) - 2)
            current_top = Create_HR(ufMarkDown, oConcat("_", sClean_Data, randomNum), current_top)
        Else
            current_top = Create_StdTxt(ufMarkDown, oConcat("_", sClean_Data, randomNum), current_top, sClean_Data)
        End If
        ufMarkDown.ScrollHeight = current_top + 20
    Next i
    
    
End Sub
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Public Functions
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Private Functions
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Function Clean_N_Trim(vinput As Variant) As String
    Clean_N_Trim = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(vinput))
End Function
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' UserForm Builder Subroutines / Functions
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Sub Create_ufBaseForm(parentObj As Object, compName As String, dleft As Double, dTop As Double, dHeight As Double, dWidth As Double)
    Set ufBaseForm = parentObj.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", oConcat("_", compName, "ufBaseForm"))
    With ufBaseForm
        .Width = dWidth
        .Height = dHeight
        .Top = dTop
        .Left = dleft
        .SpecialEffect = 0 'Flat
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
        .backColor = parentObj.backColor 'RGB(255, 255, 255)
        
    End With
End Sub
' ------------------
Private Sub Create_ufMarkDown(parentObj As Object)
    Set ufMarkDown = parentObj.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", oConcat("_", "ufMarkDown", "Frame_To_Del"))
    With ufMarkDown
        .Width = .parent.Width
        .Height = .parent.Height - 2
        .Top = 2
        .Left = 0
        .SpecialEffect = 0 'Flat
        .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
        .KeepScrollBarsVisible = fmScrollBarsNone
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
    End With
End Sub
' ------------------
Private Function Create_Header(parentObj As Object, compName As String, ByVal dTop As String, ByVal sCaption As String) As Double
    Dim header As MSForms.Label
    
    Set header = parentObj.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", compName & "Header") 'oConcat("_", CompName, "Header"))
    With header
        .AutoSize = False
        
        .Top = dTop + ELM_GAP
        .Left = ELM_LEFT
        .Width = .parent.Width - (header.Left * 2)
        
        .Font.name = "Segoe UI SemiBold"
        .Font.size = 16
        .ForeColor = RGB(103, 106, 108)
        
        .caption = sCaption
        .WordWrap = True
        .AutoSize = True
    End With
    
    Create_Header = header.Top + header.Height
End Function
' ------------------
Private Function Create_HR(parentObj As Object, compName As String, ByVal dTop As Double) As Double
    Dim hr As MSForms.Label
    
    Set hr = parentObj.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", oConcat("_", compName, "HR"))
    With hr
        .backColor = RGB(103, 106, 108)
        .Height = 1.5
        .Left = ELM_LEFT
        .Width = .parent.Width - (ELM_LEFT * 2) - 2
        .Top = dTop + ELM_HR_GAP
    End With
    Create_HR = hr.Top + hr.Height
End Function
' ------------------
Private Function Create_OL(parentObj As Object, compName As String, ByVal dTop As String, ByVal sCaption As String) As Double
    Dim OL_Bullet As MSForms.Label
    Dim OL_Text As MSForms.Label
    
    Set OL_Bullet = parentObj.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", compName & "TESTSAA") 'oConcat("_", CompName, "OL_Bullet"))
    With OL_Bullet
        .Top = dTop + ELM_GAP
        .Left = ELM_OL_LEFT
        .Width = 9.75
        .Height = 9.75
        
        .Font.name = "Segoe UI SemiBold"
        .Font.size = 10
        .ForeColor = RGB(103, 106, 108)
        .caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8226)
    End With
    ' -----
    Set OL_Text = parentObj.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", oConcat("_", compName, "OL_Text"))
    With OL_Text
        .AutoSize = False
        
        .caption = sCaption
        .ForeColor = RGB(103, 106, 108)
        .Font.name = "Segoe UI"
        .Font.size = 10
        
        .Top = OL_Bullet.Top
        .Left = OL_Bullet.Left + OL_Bullet.Width + 2
        .Width = .parent.Width - .Left
        
        .WordWrap = True
        .AutoSize = True
    End With
    Create_OL = OL_Text.Top + OL_Text.Height
End Function
' ------------------
Private Function Create_StdTxt(parentObj As Object, compName As String, ByVal dTop As String, ByVal sCaption As String) As Double
    Dim StdTxt As MSForms.Label
    
    Set StdTxt = parentObj.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", oConcat("_", compName, "StdTxt"))
    With StdTxt
        .AutoSize = False
        
        .Top = dTop + ELM_GAP
        .Left = ELM_LEFT
        .Width = .parent.Width - (ELM_LEFT * 2)
        
        .Font.name = "Segoe UI"
        .Font.size = 10
        .ForeColor = RGB(103, 106, 108)
        
        .caption = sCaption
        .WordWrap = True
        .AutoSize = True
    End With
    Create_StdTxt = StdTxt.Top + StdTxt.Height
End Function
' ------------------
Private Sub BuildAboveBan(parentObject As Object)
    Dim ufHeaderUpperBan As MSForms.Label
    Set ufHeaderUpperBan = parentObject.Controls.Add("Forms.label.1", "Definitions_AboveBan")
    With ufHeaderUpperBan
        .Top = 0
        .Width = parentObject.parent.Width
        .Height = 2
        .Left = 0
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
        .backColor = RGB(216, 221, 224)
    End With
End Sub
```

Link: https://gist.github.com/Brostoffed/9b9840749da3abe1bd738ee689026820