# GetFromClipboard and keep format in a RichTextBox

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard, rtf

I run into a issue while pasting something in my InkEdit component.

I'm trying to copy and paste some text from a Word document. This text have style.

When I paste it like this :

```
Dim MyData As DataObject

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   MyData.GetFromClipboard
   InkEdit1.TextRTF = MyData.GetText(1)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Set MyData = New DataObject
End Sub
```

The style is gone. Is there a way to get the text and paste it with the style ? Thanks.

Comment: If you paste it will ctrl + v does it paste with formatting?

Comment: This question might help: [Excel VBA copy Cell contents to a InkEdit text box and keep for formatting including colour/bold etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674641/excel-vba-copy-cell-contents-to-a-inkedit-text-box-and-keep-for-formatting-inclu)

Comment: Yes manually with CTRL+V it does paste with formatting

Comment: @erazorv4 great link but will it keep picture and for example table ?

Comment: Not sure but try the top answer, If you edit that one, it looks like it might work. Edit: Just realised there are 2 top answers. I mean the answer from @Comintern

Comment: Nice one indeed, i think it might work just how to tell what is my range as it a copy from word ?

Comment: If you already have it in your clipboard, you should not need the copy part. Only the paste part.

Comment: It's working thanks !

Comment: Now do you know if i can remove pictures from this paste ?

Comment: Sorry no idea how to do that. Maybe one of the other answers doesn't include pictures, but I'm not sure.